# Is there a way to hibernate a docker container

Tags: docker

I like to use Jupyter Notebook.  If I run it in a VM in virtualbox, I can save the state of the VM, and then pick up right where I left off the next day.  Can I do something similar if I were to run it in a docker container?  i.e. dump the "state" of the container to disk, then crank it back up and reload the "state"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like `docker checkpoint` may be the thing I'm attempting to accomplish here.  There's not much in the docs that describes it as such.  In fact, the docs for `docker checkpoint` say "Manage checkpoints" which is massively unhelpful.

**UPDATE:** This IS, in fact, what docker checkpoint is supposed to accomplish.  When I checkpoint my jupyter notebook container, it saves it, I can start it back up with `docker start --checkpoint [my_checkpoint] jupyter_notebook`, and it shows the things I had running as being in a `Running` state.  However, attempts to then use the `Running` notebooks fail.  I'm not sure if this is a CRIU issue or a Jupyter issue, but I'll bring it up in the appropriate git issue tracker.

Anyhoo `docker checkpoint` is the thing that is supposed to provide VM-save-state/hibernate style functionality.

Comment: Did you solve this for the Jupyer use case? I'm wondering if this will work with a Kubernetes JupyterHub setup we have.

Comment: I was doing a Jupyterhub Kubernetes combo whilst at a previous company!  Anyhoo, that's neither here nor there.  I never got this to work, because I stopped trying.  If this has been fixed, and you figure it out, I will upvote and accept your answer instead.

Comment: [Here is the issue I opened](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/419).  It has since been closed due to inactivity.  You might find some of this info helpful, tho.

Answer (score 7):

The closest approach I can see is `docker pause <container-id>`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pause/

> The docker pause command suspends all processes in the specified containers. On Linux, this uses the cgroups freezer. Traditionally, when suspending a process the SIGSTOP signal is used, which is observable by the process being suspended. With the cgroups freezer the process is unaware, and unable to capture, that it is being suspended, and subsequently resumed.

Take into account as an important difference against VirtualBox hibernation, that there is no disk persistence of the memory state of the containerized process.

Answer (score -5):

If you just stop the container, it hibernates:

```
docker stop myjupyter
(hours pass)
docker start myjupyter
docker attach myjupyter
```

I do this all the time, especially with docker containers which have web browers in them.

Comment: "The main process inside the container will receive SIGTERM, and after a grace period, SIGKILL" -- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/

This doesn't sound like what I'm looking for...

Comment: Jupyter automatically saves your working environment periodically, so this works, I do it all the time.  You're right that it might not work for other programs.

Comment: But if I have a variable that took 2 days to compute, when I docker start my container again, I'll have to recompute it.  The goal is not to save the stuff I type, it's to save the work that the computer has done.

Comment: Yah, I assumed that it was to save the stuff you typed.